# PHP Update MySQL table using HTML form

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

I am trying to update my MySQL table by using a form in an HTML page.

This is my PHP code

```
    <?php
 ob_start();
 session_start();
 require_once 'dbconnect.php';

 if( !isset($_SESSION['client']) ) {
  header("Location: homepage_login.php");
  exit;
 }
 // select loggedin users detail
 $res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM clients WHERE client_id=".$_SESSION['client']);
 $userRow=mysql_fetch_array($res);

 if( isset($_POST['btn-book']) ) { 

 $sql="UPDATE appointments SET date='$slot_date', line='$slot_line', reason='$reason' WHERE id='$id'";
 $result=mysql_query($sql);

 if($result){
echo "Successful";
}

else {
echo "ERROR";
} }

?>
```

And my HTML form

```
<form action"" method"post">

       <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" name="date"></p>

       <br>
       <br>
       Select a line:
       <ol id="selectable" name="line">
  <li class="ui-widget-content">Line 1</li>
  <li class="ui-widget-content">Line 2</li>
  <li class="ui-widget-content">Line 3</li>
  <li class="ui-widget-content">Line 4</li>
  <li class="ui-widget-content">Line 5</li>
  <li class="ui-widget-content">Line 6</li>
  <li class="ui-widget-content">Line 7</li>
</ol>
<br>
<br>

     <p>Reason for appointment: <input type="text" name="reaosn"></p>

        <div class="form-group">
             <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-primary" name="btn-book">Book</button>
            </div>

            </form>
```

These are on the same page by the way. So what I need to happen is for when someone fills out the form and hits the submit button, the PHP code will update my MySQL table on a specific already made record.

I'm not sure if I somehow need to specify what record I want to update or if I've just completely messed up actually updating my table.

So, my questions is:

How do I update a specific record in my table using a HTML form and PHP code?

Comment: update query in the sql. just go through..http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_update.asp

Comment: I'm not sure what the actual question is? Are you getting any errors ?

Comment: I'm not getting any errors, it's just my code won't update a record in my table

Comment: `$sql="UPDATE appointments SET date='$slot_date', line='$slot_line', reason='$reason' WHERE id='$_SESSION[client]'";`  i think your $id and the session name  are same.if same use the above code.

Comment: it will not update. you are not mention `$id` yet

Comment: where and how should i mention $id so that it updates???

Comment: `$id=$userRow['client_id'];` please add this after    `$userRow=mysql_fetch_array($res);`

Answer (score 0):

in the form  you  have to change like this

```
<form method="post" action="same_page.php">
```

the php change with below code.

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();
require_once 'dbconnect.php';

if( !isset($_SESSION['client']) ) {
 header("Location: homepage_login.php");
 exit;
}
// select loggedin users detail
$res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM clients WHERE client_id='$_SESSION[client]'");
$userRow=mysql_fetch_array($res);
$id=$userRow['client_id'];

if( isset($_POST['btn-book']) ) { 

 $slot_date= $_POST['date'];
 $reason=$_POST['reason'];
 $slot_line=$_POST['line'];

 $sql="UPDATE appointments SET date='$slot_date', line='$slot_line', reason='$reason' WHERE id='$id'";
 $result=mysql_query($sql);

 if($result){
  echo "Successful";
 }else {
  echo "ERROR";
 } 
}

?>
```

Comment: **Danger**: This code is [vulnerable to XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS) User input (such as PHP_SELF) needs escaping before being inserted into an HTML document!.

Comment: Thanks for helping, but now when I click submit my page says that the url can't be found? I'm unsure if it's trying to find a new page which I haven't created/defined or something else?

Comment: please type your same page url inside action filed in the form.

Comment: @Isabella yours should be `<form action"" method="post">` not what Jees added as his directs you to the URL same_page.php

Comment: Thanks for all your help, the first time I tried is using the above code it worked. And then I tried again and it stopped working? Now it comes up with the message ERROR which is obviously the echo command...

Comment: Yes That is... ;)  @Isabella

Answer (score 0):

Just **echo** all the values on form

for e.g:  `<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" name="date"></p>` into  `<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" value="<?php echo $result['date']; ?> " name="date"></p>`