# Use jQuery selectable to insert info into MYSQL table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

Basically, I want to use jQuery selectable to update rows in MySQL. I thought it would be pretty simple but everything I've tried hasn't worked so far.

This is my Javascript:

```
<script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
    altField: "#alternate",
      altFormat: "DD, d MM, yy" });
    $( "#selectable" ).selectable();
  });
  </script>
```

My PHP code:

```
if( isset($_POST['btn-book']) ) { 

$slot_date = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($_POST['slot_date']));
 $slot_line=$_POST['slot_line'];
 $reason=$_POST['reason'];
 $id=$_POST['id'];

 $sql="UPDATE appointments SET slot_date='$slot_date', slot_line='$slot_line', reason='$reason' WHERE id='$id'";
 $result=mysql_query($sql);
```

And my HTML form:

```
Please select a line:      
<ol name="slot_line" id="selectable" >
  <li class="ui-widget-content">Line 1</li>
  <li class="ui-widget-content">Line 2</li>
  <li class="ui-widget-content">Line 3</li>
  <li class="ui-widget-content">Line 4</li>
  <li class="ui-widget-content">Line 5</li>
  <li class="ui-widget-content">Line 6</li>
  <li class="ui-widget-content">Line 7</li>
</ol>
```

All I want to happen is when the user selects a line in my HTML form and presses the submit button, 'slot_line' in my MySQL table is updated.

Comment: You can have a hidden input where you assign the value of the selected `slot_line`.

Comment: Let me guess, your MySQL table shows up as all 0000-00-00, correct?

Comment: You then took this line `$slot_date = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($slot_date));` from an answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/38964342/ that was given in your other question http://stackoverflow.com/q/38964225/ which you posted not once, not twice, but thrice. If you show us what the db schema was... maybe there's an error made in there.

Comment: possible exact duplicates of [jQuery datepicker update MySQL rows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38953254/jquery-datepicker-update-mysql-rows) and [jQuery datepicker in HTML form to update MySQL rows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38964225/jquery-datepicker-in-html-form-to-update-mysql-rows)

Comment: Check for errors via MySQL http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php and apply it to your query. Then via PHP http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and look at your console; there isn't anything using a POST method in what you posted. You'll need to tell us what your db schema is also. I'm trying to help you here, so if you won't respond to my comments, you can have a look at Logan's answer. Lord as my witness, I tried.

Answer (score 0):

`<ol></ol>` is not an input field. Remove the `name` tag of your `ol`.

What you can do is to have a hidden input where you can store the value of the selected `slot line`.

```
<input type="hidden" name="slot_line" id="slot_line">
```

Then create a script to assign a value to your hidden input:

```
$(document).on("click", ".ui-widget-content", function(){

    var elem = $(this),
        slotitem = elem.text();

    $("#slot_line").val(slotitem);

});
```

---

And for @Fred -ii-'s investigation, you can alternatively try using HTML5's date:

```
<input type="date" name="slot_date">
```

Make sure that your `slot_date` column on your `appointments` table is in `date` data type.

Comment: Wishing you a green tick here ;-) As for my "investigation", well.. the question here and the other two to me, are way too unclear to have submitted an answer. When I don't know which animal(s) I'm dealing with here exactly, I have to go out "hunting" ;-) Firstly, we don't know if the connection API used was successful and which one. We also don't know what type the date column is. If it's anything other than `date`, it's failing on them. Way too many unknowns for this country bumpkin. I know a busted tractor when I see one. ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- thanks for the support! I've checked the link to her other question. We know that her `UPDATE` query is working, so her connection API must be working, it's just that the date is not properly inserting/updating. So it is up to OP now if she can figure out all the answers that was given to her.

Comment: You're welcome Logan. Well, that's where proper error checking and reporting comes in, along with looking at the console. I doubt she's doing that and probably not seeing what's wrong (if any errors are present). Up until we know that, then there isn't much else that you or I can do. I'd pop another comment up there, but would probably just be done in vain, so the ball's in her court now.

Comment: Btw, another similar question of hers, goes back as far as August the 3rd http://stackoverflow.com/q/38738618/ - Seems she's been battling with it ever since. Nobody even posted any links for error checking. I just posted some under her question now. The code doesn't correspond with any POST whatsoever also and no form tags to be found anywhere.

Comment: Thank you both @Fred-ii- but I have since figured out the answer and wasn't able to come online to try your suggestions and reply to your comments. And in case you were wondering, my connection API is successful, the table format for 'slot_date' is date, but that's not what I'm asking in this specific question, and I have always done error and console checking but that rarely helps me figure out my problem. Thanks again for trying to help me.